# How to get CUDNN to work with lda2vec on aws ubuntu GPU instance?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, nlp, cudnn

I have been trying to use lda2vec to work with the GPU as stated here

```
http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/cemoody/lda2vec/blob/master/examples/twenty_newsgroups/lda.ipynb#topic=5&lambda=0.6&term=
```

I have successfully installed CUDA, Chainer (1.6.0), and CUDNN but when I run the program with GPU as True I get the following:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CuDNNError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-29fdc8451bd9> in <module>()
 11         model.to_gpu()
 12     model.fit(flattened, categorical_features=[doc_ids], fraction=1e-3,
---> 13               epochs=1)
 14     model.to_cpu()
 15 serializers.save_hdf5('model.hdf5', model)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda2vec-0.1-py2.7.egg/lda2vec/lda2vec.pyc in fit(self, words_flat, categorical_features, targets, epochs, fraction)
436                 this_fraction = len(chunk) * 1.0 / words_flat.shape[0]
437                 self.fit_partial(chunk, this_fraction,
--> 438                                  categorical_features=cat_feats)
439 
440     def prepare_topics(self, categorical_feature_name, vocab, temperature=1.0):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda2vec-0.1-py2.7.egg/lda2vec/lda2vec.pyc in fit_partial(self, words_flat, fraction, categorical_features, targets)
385         # Before calculating gradients, zero them or we will get NaN
386         self.zerograds()
--> 387         prior_loss = self._priors()
388         words_loss = self._skipgram_flat(words_flat, categorical_features)
389         trget_loss = self._target(vcategorical_features, targets)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda2vec-0.1-py2.7.egg/lda2vec/lda2vec.pyc in _priors(self)
163             embedding, transform, loss_func, penalty = vals
164             name = cat_feat_name + "_mixture"
--> 165             dl = dirichlet_likelihood(self[name].weights)
166             if penalty:
167                 factors = self[name].factors.W

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lda2vec-0.1-py2.7.egg/lda2vec/dirichlet_likelihood.pyc in dirichlet_likelihood(weights, alpha)
 30         proportions = F.softmax(weights)
 31     else:
---> 32         proportions = F.softmax(weights.W)
 33     loss = (alpha - 1.0) * F.log(proportions + 1e-8)
 34     return -F.sum(loss)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/functions/activation/softmax.pyc in softmax(x, use_cudnn)
 90 
 91     """
---> 92     return Softmax(use_cudnn)(x)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/function.pyc in __call__(self, *inputs)
103         # Forward prop
104         with cuda.get_device(*in_data):
--> 105             outputs = self.forward(in_data)
106             assert type(outputs) == tuple
107 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chainer/functions/activation/softmax.pyc in forward(self, x)
 34             one = numpy.array(1, dtype=dtype).ctypes
 35             zero = numpy.array(0, dtype=dtype).ctypes
---> 36             handle = cudnn.get_handle()
 37             x_cube = x[0].reshape(x[0].shape[:2] + (-1, 1))
 38             desc = cudnn.create_tensor_descriptor(x_cube)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cupy/cudnn.pyc in get_handle()
 16     handle = _handles.get(device.id, None)
 17     if handle is None:
---> 18         handle = cudnn.create()
 19         _handles[device.id] = handle
 20     return handle

cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx in cupy.cuda.cudnn.create (cupy/cuda/cudnn.cpp:1567)()

cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx in cupy.cuda.cudnn.create (cupy/cuda/cudnn.cpp:1512)()

cupy/cuda/cudnn.pyx in cupy.cuda.cudnn.check_status (cupy/cuda/cudnn.cpp:1311)()

CuDNNError: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

I have copied the correct files to the CUDA directory and added the path in the bashrc. I have no prior GPU computing question so any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about trying to get LDA2Vec to work, but this looks like you missed something in setting up CUDA. Installing CuDNN from scratch is painful.

As of October 2016, AWS is offering pre-built AMI's with NVIDIA CUDA 7.5 Pre-installed.

Please see these blog posts. Get a new AMI with CUDA pre installed and then try tour code again.

[AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-p2-instance-type-for-amazon-ec2-up-to-16-gpus/)

[AWS AMI GPU Image](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZMLK1K?qid=1475196062961&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title)

[NVIDIA Digits4](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01LZN28VD?qid=1475196062961&sr=0-3&ref_=srh_res_product_title)